# Class not found flex

Tags: apache-flex, class, actionscript

my .as class doesn't seem to link well cause I get the following error

```
A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', as the definition's package, 'MyPlayerd'.    MyPlayerd.as    /MyApp/src  Unknown Flex Problem
```

This is my class file

```
package MyPlayerd
{
public class MyPlayerd
{

    public static var spelerID:String = new String();
    private static var _voornaam:String =  new String();
    public static var famnaam:String = "";
    public static var land:String = "";
    public static var gebdatum:Date;
    public static var speeltsinds:Date;
    public static var gewicht:int = new int();
    public static var win:int=0;
    private static var _loss:int=0;


    public function MyPlayerd()
    {

    }


    public static function get voornaam():String
    {
        return _voornaam;
    }

    public static function set voornaam(value:String):void
    {
        _voornaam = value;
    }

    public static function get loss():int
    {
        return _loss;
    }

    public static function set loss(value:int):void
    {
        _loss = value;
    }

}

 }
```

I import it like this

```
import MyPlayerd.*;
```

and create variable like this

```
public var p1:MyPlayerd = new MyPlayerd();
```

Answer (score 0):

> A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '',
>   as the definition's package, 'MyPlayerd'.

This is saying your `MyPlayerd` class is in the package named "MyPlayerd" but the location of the file in your project is the default package (which has no name and is represented by the empty quotes in the error above).

The package name and the class's location in your project must match.

The solution is either to move the `MyPlayerd` class into a folder named: `/MyApp/src/MyPlayerd`

Or, remove the package name from your class (on the first line):

```
package
{
    public class MyPlayerd
    {
      // rest of class here
     }
}
```